# Why is the superconstructor being called? and why am I getting an error printing to screen?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I am learning java Programming. I am getting the Compilation Error when I try to run the below program.

```
public class Animal {
    public Animal() {
        System.out.println(“Making an Animal”);
    }
}

public class Hippo extends Animal {
    public Hippo() {
        System.out.println(“Making a Hippo”);
    }
}

public class TestHippo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
         System.out.println(“Starting...”);
         Hippo h = new Hippo();
    }
}
```

As per my understanding, If this progragram runs without an error, it will print

> Starting...
>
> Making a Hippo

But in the "Head First Java" book, They mentioned the output of the program is

> Starting...
>
> Making an Animal
>
> Making a Hippo

How is this output possible? I didnt call the super class constructor, but how come "Making an Animal" printed Here.

Can anyone explain the logic behind this?

If we call the subclass constructor, is its superclass constrtuctor also executed?

And also why I am getting Compilation Error, I am using the Online IDE to test the basic java programs.

**Error Details**

> Compilation error  comments (0)   stdin copy Standard input is empty 
>   compilation info Main.java:3: error: illegal character: \8220
>   System.out.println(?Making an Animal?);
>                      ^ Main.java:3: error: ';' expected System.out.println(?Making an Animal?);
>                       ^ Main.java:3: error: illegal character: \8221 System.out.println(?Making an Animal?);
>                                       ^ Main.java:8: error: illegal character: \8220 System.out.println(?Making a Hippo?);
>                      ^ Main.java:8: error: ';' expected System.out.println(?Making a Hippo?);
>                       ^ Main.java:8: error: illegal character: \8221 System.out.println(?Making a Hippo?);
>                                     ^ Main.java:13: error: illegal character: \8220 System.out.println(?Starting...?);
>                      ^ Main.java:13: error: ';' expected System.out.println(?Starting...?);
>                       ^ Main.java:13: error: illegal start of expression System.out.println(?Starting...?);
>                               ^ Main.java:13: error: illegal character: \8221 System.out.println(?Starting...?);
>                                  ^ Main.java:13: error: illegal start of expression System.out.println(?Starting...?);
>                                   ^ 11 errors

Comment: Try using normal quotes, e.g. `"` instead of those fancy italic ones.

Comment: Check your quotation marks!

Comment: Ignoring you have invalid quotes in your code, I'd say the chapter in the book where that code comes from explains it in great detail.

Comment: You should really have posted this as two separate questions - one asking why you got the compilation error, and one asking about the superclass constructor.  That way, you could accept an answer about the invalid quotation marks for the first question; then accept an answer about constructor chaining for the second question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

> Note: If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass
>   constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the
>   no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not
>   have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error.
>   Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only
>   superclass, there is no problem.

So when you dont call explicitly `super()`, le compiler inserts it for you . 
The equivalent is

```
public class Hippo extends Animal {
  public Hippo() {
    super()
    System.out.println(“Making a Hippo”);
  }
}
```

**Edit:** As pointed out by Chris, the problem reported by the stacktrace comes from the wrong quotes you used.

It should be

```
" "
```

instead of

```
“ ”
```

Comment: Well, if this is the answer being voted up, you may want to address the issue about the fancy quotes so it's at least complete :)

Comment: @ccheneson So, if this is the case, we no need to mention the Super() by overselves. Compiler will take care everytime. right?

Comment: @Padmanabhan Vijay : Yes, you can omit the call to super() and the compiler will call it for you

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your compilation error is caused by using the fancy quotes `“ ”` instead of regular quotes `" "`.  This often happens if you're writing your code in Word and then pasting it into another program to compile it.

For the constructor part, if there is no explicit super call (with or without arguments), the no-arguments `super()` call is done implicitly - see docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).

Answer (score 0):

Just to sum up:

> How is this output possible? I didnt call the super class constructor, but how come "Making an Animal" printed Here.

Superclasses their constructors are called automatically before executing the code in the current constructor (same effect as explicitly calling `super()` on the first line), even if you don't explicitly add this

> Why am I getting Compilation Error?

You're not using the correct quotes. Use `"` instead of your calligraphy stuff.

You can verify they're different with this:

```
System.out.println((int) '"'); // 34
System.out.println((int) '”'); // 8221
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about constructor chaining to understand this concept in detail.
By default, every constructor in java will either have call to super call constructor or other overloaded constructor in the same class.

For ex :

```
public Hippo() {
System.out.println(“Making a Hippo”);
}
```

This is same as below invocation.

```
public Hippo() {
super(); // Animal class constructor in your case
System.out.println(“Making a Hippo”);
}
```

An article to understand [constructor chaining](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/constructor-chaining-in-java-calling-another-constructor.html) briefly.
Also to resolve compilation issue:

Replace double quote `“...”` with `"..."` in all the SysOut statements.

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error comes from your quotes “ ”, they should be normal unformatted " "

Answer (score 0):

The default superclass constructor is automatically called.
See [Creation of New Class Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) in the Java Language Specification:

> This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor
>   invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If
>   this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this
>   constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a
>   superclass constructor (using super). Evaluate the arguments and
>   process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these
>   same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly,
>   then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise,
>   continue with step 4.

This may sound pretty complicated, but there is an example below it that is almost the same as your example.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, every constructor either implicitly or explicitly calls a super constructor. In the implicit case (i.e. if you don't manually call `super(...)`) this just calls the nullary (no-args) super constructor, i.e. any constructor like this:

```
Class(...) {
    // code...
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
Class(...) {
    super();
    // code...
}
```

An implication of this is that you have to use `super(...)` if the superclass does not define a nullary constructor (a class without any constructor implicitly defines a public nullary constructor).

Answer (score -3):

The first line of the constructor is super();
Hence it will call the constructor present in the super class

Comment: This is false/misleading - `super()` is **not** the "first line of the constructor" - rather it is implicitly called first if there is no other call to any other super constructor. `super(1,2,3)` may be used, in which case, no call to `super()` will be made.